# Is there a gem or solution to Inviting users from benelux social network site ""hyves.nl"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, api, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Are there any GEMS or solutions for inviting users from the dutch/Benelux socialnetwork Hyves?
They supply some PHP code for this wich ofcourse could be converted and after searching for a long time I dont think anything exists yet for ruby but still.

www.hyves.nl is the site for reference

Anyone has a solution to connect to this and invite people with there API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `hyves_oauth`, but I'm not sure about the status of that project (at version 0.0.2 from july 2011).

Instead, try Omniauth with Omniauth-oauth: https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-oauth. Hyves talks OAuth AFAIK.